# Filter and Sort Projects in Visual Studio 2019 For Better Management Of Multiple Startup Projects

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions, app-startup

My team works on a solution in Visual Studio 2019.  The solution contains many dozens of projects.  We do use solution filters, but there are occasions where it is more convenient overall to load the entire solution.

One thing that's less convenient is configuring multiple startup projects in a solution with many projects.

[image: screenshot of startup project property page]

Is there any way to filter or sort the list of projects? Alternatively is there any way to define "profiles" of multiple start-up projects and apply start up actions as a group?

Extensions would work for me if needed, but I'd rather do this without extending the IDE if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SwitchStartupProject](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProjectForVS2019) extension lets you select the startup project from a dropdown and switch between multi-project startup configurations.